# Pandas groupby and sum not giving correct values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to group my data by country then by year and sum up the value columns using pandas. Currently I am reading in the csv file and using the following:

```
data_cleaned= df.groupby(['Country', 'year'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Here is a sample of my dataset:

```
Country year  value
Angola  2009    0
Angola  2009    0
Angola  2010    0
Angola  2010    0
Angola  2010    0
Angola  2010    0
Angola  2011    0
Angola  2011    0
Angola  2011    0
Angola  2011    0
Angola  2012    118
Angola  2012    0
Angola  2012    0
Angola  2012    0
Angola  2013    0
Angola  2013    0
Angola  2013    0
Angola  2013    0
Angola  2014    0
Angola  2014    0
Angola  2014    0
Angola  2014    0
Angola  2015    0
Angola  2015    0
Angola  2015    0
Angola  2015    0
Angola  2016    0
Angola  2016    0
Angola  2016    0
Angola  2016    0
Angola  2017    0
Australia   2009    0
Australia   2009    14
Australia   2009    0
Australia   2009    12
Australia   2010    0
Australia   2010    0
Australia   2010    54
Australia   2010    6
Australia   2011    0
Australia   2011    4
Australia   2011    17
Australia   2011    13
Australia   2012    8
Australia   2012    2
Australia   2012    4
Australia   2012    105
Australia   2013    0
Australia   2013    5
Australia   2013    0
Australia   2013    0
Australia   2014    0
Australia   2014    0
Australia   2014    0
Australia   2014    0
Australia   2015    0
Australia   2015    0
Australia   2015    0
Australia   2015    0
Australia   2016    0
Australia   2016    0
Australia   2016    0
Australia   2016    0
Australia   2017    0
```

But I get the following results:

```
Partner Country year    value
0   Angola  2009    0.00
1   Angola  2010    0.00
2   Angola  2011    0.00
3   Angola  2012    86,280.00
4   Angola  2013    0.00
5   Angola  2014    0.00
6   Angola  2015    0.00
7   Angola  2016    0.00
8   Angola  2017    0.00
9   Australia   2009    54,879.00
10  Australia   2010    67,899.00
11  Australia   2011    50,965.00
12  Australia   2012    332,128.00
13  Australia   2013    16,515.00
14  Australia   2014    0.00
15  Australia   2015    0.00
16  Australia   2016    0.00
17  Australia   2017    0.00
```

Which is obviously wrong since Angola only has one non-zero value and it's in 2012, which is the correct year to have a value but I'm expecting 118 instead of 86,280.00.   Could someone maybe point out what I am doing wrong and how I can correctly sum the value column based on the Country and year columns?

Comment: I tried running your code and it returns 118 for Angola,2012. Could you check the datatypes for the columns?Is it int64 for "value"?

Comment: I'm getting dtype('float64') for value, since for some of the data I am not showing there are floats. Do you think that might have something to do with it?

Comment: Yes. That should be the reason. Can you change the datatype to int64 and try?

Comment: First I did data['value'] = data['value'].astype('int64'), then I ran the groupby code again, but now for Angola I am getting 86280.

Comment: I will check the data again to see if I can find something strange, thank you for pointing out the data type for now

Comment: I copy pasted your data into an excel file. read it into a pandas df.worked fine for me.

Comment: yup but that's only a small portion of the data so I will try to look at the other parts to see if I can figure it out. Thank you for trying.